# Error in installing gitignore_parser as part of taipy installation

Tags: installation, taipy

I am installing taipy in a local pip install mode as my work laptop does not have connectivity to the internet.  During the installation, I am facing issue at the  gitignore_parser package.  The error message prompted was "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)" and "No matching distribution found for wheel".  I checked all the files that I have downloaded for taipy installation and saw that only gitignore_parser is a .gz file instead of .whl file.  Does anyone know how to overcome this error?

I am able to install it successfully when I do a pip install taipy from my other machine that is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the packages that are in .gz file on a machine with internet connection and retreived the .whl file from the wheel cache during the installation.  The .whl file can be used for the offline installation.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to install Taipy offline is too complex. An [issue](https://github.com/Avaiga/taipy/issues/308) has been created to answer this problem.